# Android. How to use composable TextField from Java code?

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-compose-textfield

I have custom composable InputTextField. I needed to use this field to enter text from Java code. For this I created a helper method in Kotlin:

```
fun ComposeView.initInputField(
    text: String,
    onValueChanged: (String) -> Unit,
    isEditable: Boolean = true,
) {
    setContent {
        RncbTheme {
            InputTextField(
                text = text, 
                onValueChange = onValueChanged,
                isEditable = isEditable,
             )
    }
}
```

Here is my java code:

```
 @Override
    public void initComposeInputFiled(String initialText) {
 
        InputFieldKt.initInputField(composeInputView, initialText, s -> {
            // onValueChange
            return Unit.INSTANCE;
        });
    }
```

The problem is that I don't quite understand how to manage this field from Java code. Should I call the `initComposeInputFiled`  method every time if I need to write a specific value to a field ?
And how can you get the current value that is entered into a field from Java code?

Please, help me.

Comment: I will be somewhat surprised if this works well for you. "And how can you get the current value that is entered into a field from Java code?" -- in your code sample, I think it is `s`. It is the parameter passed to the `onValueChanged` callback, and you will need to not only hold onto it yourself, but need to supply it back to `InputTextField()` as `text`.

Comment: @CommonsWare,
"but need to supply it back to InputTextField() as text". Did I understand you correctly, I will need  in Java code inside onValueChangeCallback call the initComposeInputFiled again with s ?

Comment: You will need to do something like that. Put Java aside for a moment and focus on Compose. I am assuming that `InputTextField()` is from your design system and wraps `TextField()` or `BasicTextField()`. If so, those are stateless. If you were to write this purely in Kotlin and Compose, the value passed to `onValueChanged` would typically go in a `MutableState` that you `remember()`, and the `text` parameter to the field would reference that state. That is how the field knows the text to render without it holding its own state: you pass in that text on each recomposition.

Comment: The fact that you're trying to all of this from Java does not change that. You will still need to manage the state in your own code; it's just that this code is Java. That's why I am skeptical that this will work, as I don't know how recompositions are going to hold up in this approach.

Comment: You might be better served creating a stateful field, wrapping that in a dedicated `ComposeView`, then using that as an ordinary `View` from Java.

Comment: Have you come across examples of such implementation? since I am new in jetpack compose it is difficult for me to perceive information in words

Comment: I have not tried to do this in general, let alone from something wrapped in a `ComposeView` -- sorry!